# Is there a way to get the file path of the .java file executed or compiled?

Tags: java, netbeans, path

In Python the global variable `__file__` is the full path of the current file.

`System.getProperty("user.dir");` seems to return the path of the current working directory.

I want to get the path of the current .java, .class or package file.

Then use this to get the path to an image.

My project file structure in Netbeans looks like this: [image: files]
<sub>(source: [toile-libre.org](http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1475433676.png))</sub>

---

Update to use code suggested from my chosen best answer:

```
    // read image data from picture in package
    try {
        InputStream instream = TesseractTest.class
            .getResourceAsStream("eurotext.tif");
                 
        bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(instream);            
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

This code is used in the usage example from [tess4j](https://github.com/nguyenq/tess4j).

My full code of the usage example is [here](https://github.com/jtara1/TesseractTest/blob/master/src/tesseracttest/TesseractTest.java).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to load an image file stored right next to your class file, use [`Class::getResourceAsStream(String name)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-).

In your case, that would be:

```
try (InputStream instream = TesseractTest.class.getResourceAsStream("eurotext.tif")) {
    // read stream here
}
```

This assumes that your build system copies the .tif file to your `build` folder, which is commonly done by IDEs, but requires extra setup in build tools like Ant and Gradle.

If you package your program to a .jar file, the code will still work, again assuming your build system package the .tif file next to the .class file.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to get the file path of the .java file executed or compiled?

For completeness, the literal answer to your question is "not easily and not always".

There is a round-about way to find the source filename for a class on the callstack via `StackFrameElement.getFileName()`.  However, the filename won't always be available<sup>1</sup> and it won't necessarily be correct<sup>2</sup>.

Indeed, it is quite likely that the source tree won't be present on the system where you are executing the code.  So if you needed an image file that was stashed in the source tree, you would be out of luck.

<sup>1 - It depends on the Java compiler and compilation options that you use.  And potentially on other things.</sup>

<sup>2 - For example, the source tree can be moved or removed after compilation.</sup>

---

Andreas has described the correct way to solve your problem.  Make sure that the image file is in your application's JAR file, and access it using `getResource` or `getResourceAsStream`.   If your application is using an API that requires a filename / pathname in the file system, you may need to extract the resource from the JAR to a temporary file, or something like that.

Answer (score -2):

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(getPackageParent(Main.class, false));        

}

public static String getPackageParent(Class<?> cls, boolean include_last_dot)
        throws Exception {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(cls.getPackage().getName());
    if (sb.lastIndexOf(".") > 0)
        if (include_last_dot)
            return sb.delete(sb.lastIndexOf(".") + 1, sb.length())
                    .toString();
        else
            return sb.delete(sb.lastIndexOf("."), sb.length()).toString();
    return sb.toString();
}

}
```

Comment: That will not help gain access to the .tif file stored next to the .class file inside a .jar file.